# How to required all input type text in specific div, when checkbox is checked

Tags: html, jquery

I would like all text input to be required after selecting the appropriate checkbox.
I try this code:

```
$('#some_checkbox').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.some-div input[type="text"]').prop('required', true);
    } else {
         $('.some-div input[type="text"]').prop('required', false);
    }

});
    <div class="some-div">
        <input type="text" name"foo" placeholder="foo">
        <input type="text" name"foo2" placeholder="foo">
    </div>
```

But not working

Comment: Please include your html, without it's very hard to tell you what the problem is. Also I just ran your code and it's working just fine.

Comment: it's very funny because now it also working for me :D

Comment: actually nothing, before I asked, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `=` sign is missing on the `name` attribute of your text inputs.

Next just for testing and demonstrating I've added a formular with a submit button and your desired checkbox. The function `onChangeSomeCheckbox()` will change the `required` property of all inputs with the type text in the class given of the `data-required` from the checkbox.

```js
$('#some_checkbox').on('change', onChangeSomeCheckbox);

function onChangeSomeCheckbox(event) {
  var $checkbox = $(event.target);
  $($checkbox.data('required') + ' input[type="text"]').prop('required', $checkbox.prop('checked'));
}
```

```css
input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="some_checkbox">
  require texts
  <input type="checkbox" id="some_checkbox" data-required=".some-div" />
</label>

<form>
  <div class="some-div">
    <input type="text" name="foo" placeholder="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="foo2" placeholder="foo" />
  </div>
  
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```